# Are Green Potatoes OK?

Tags: food-safety, potatoes, vegetables

Sometimes when peeling a potato, I find that areas of it are a bright shade of green. Does this mean that:
A) The potato is OK to eat?

B) The potato is OK to eat, as long as the green parts are removed and discarded?

C) The potato is not OK to eat (and if so, why not)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This just means the potato has been exposed to light and has produced chlorophyll (the green color). It is most likely safe to eat, minus the green areas.

Producing the chlorophyll also produces solanine, which is toxic in large quantities. Remove the green parts and don't eat more than 4lbs.

For detailed information, see this link.

http://www.wisegeek.com/are-green-potatoes-poisonous.htm

Comment: I question the "perfectly" in "perfectly safe".

Comment: The 4lbs is for a healthy adult. Different values apply to small children, pregnant women and people with existing health problems.

Answer (score 8):

The potato is OK to eat as long as the green parts are removed. They contain a toxin called solanine.

See this related question: [Is it safe to eat potatoes that have sprouted?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/is-it-safe-to-eat-potatoes-which-have-sprouted)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the core of the potato is "hard" I usually just remove the green part and cook as intended.