# Is it safe to eat the skin of a potato?

Tags: baking, potatoes, boiling, skin

Is it safe to eat the skin of a baked or boiled potato, or are there any health or sanitary reasons not to eat it?

Contrarily, are there any reasons to eat it, e.g. does the skin contain vitamins or minerals which you would cut off by peeling?

EDIT: There is a related question [Do I have to peel red potatoes before baking them?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/47304/do-i-have-to-peel-red-potatoes-before-baking-them) that asks specifically for red potatoes. This question covers yellow potatoes as well.

Comment: I'm still closing, because none of the answers to the other question is in any way specific to potato color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *usually* safe to eat the skins of potatoes.

If there is a greenish tint under the skin, you'll want to peel down to below the greenish bit.  If you don't, it could lead to solanine poisoning.

See [Is it safe to eat potatoes that have sprouted?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1260/67) and [Are Green Potatoes OK?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1331/67)