# Sprouting Potatoes in Fridge? Safe to eat?

Tags: potatoes

Have a bag of potatoes about maybe 3 weeks old. Still firmish, not green but with little small sprouts (maybe barely 1 cm) VERY small.

Are these ok to eat? I trimmed off the sprouts and the inside looked fine, and they are not green. Slightly softer but still firm.

Comment: Partial duplicate .... yours haven't gotten as far as : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1260/67 .  (I personally worry about the soft & green tint issues, myself, but I also cut a fair but away from the sprouted areas)

Comment: @Joe: Although these haven't gotten so far as the related question, I agree that it's a duplicate. The answer there is also a perfect answer for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are okay to eat. The sprouts on the other hand can be very acidic and SHOULD NOT be eaten. As long as you make sure you wash the potato thoroughly you shouldn't have to worry.