# Are my patially green and budded potatoes safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, potatoes

I got some potatoes. Some are partially budded, some are partially green. Are they safe to eat?
[image]

Comment: Hi Tim, the "green" part is covered by a second question, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1260. It's a duplicate of both.

Comment: One should still leave a TL;DR here: Sprouts, never mind, substantial green parts, TOSS.