# My red potatoes seem to have an unusually high amount of eyes. Should I cut them out?

Tags: potatoes

I got a large bag of red potatoes from costco, but it has a lot of eyes and probably 100 dimples all over it. I peeled the first one and extracted the deep eyes and it looks good underneath (no green), but why isn't it smooth like I expected? Is it safe?

Not a duplicate, it has not sprouted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to eat potatoes that have sprouted?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/is-it-safe-to-eat-potatoes-that-have-sprouted)

Comment: Nope not duplicate. This is about whether this potato has many, and there are NO SPROUTS by the way. It has NOT sprouted, and also I ate it after cooking for 30 minutes and it was great but curious if I need to dig out for the next ones.

Comment: All right, since it's been a while, I'll go ahead and [move the dup conversation to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35436/discussion-on-question-by-seasonedaddict-my-red-potatoes-seem-to-have-an-unusual). - it's a bit longer than ideal for a question and it seems like no one really thinks it's a dup.